# Upper limit of unsuccessful appeals against suspensions

Tags: rules, football, mls

From [MLS Press Box](http://pressbox.mlssoccer.com/content/appeal-review-red-card-decision),

> **Appeal to review a Send-Off Decision:**
>
> 1.Prior to the start of the MLS League Season, Clubs must post a $25,000 refundable bond with the League Office for the right to make up to two (2) unsuccessful appeals.
>
> 2.If an appeal is upheld (i.e., successful), then the send-off punishment will be rescinded.
>
> 3.If an appeal is rejected, then the send-off punishment (and any supplemental discipline should it be administered by the MLS Disciplinary Committee) will stand and the Club will have lost one of its two allotted appeals for the Season.
>
> 4.If an appeal is deemed frivolous by the Ruling Body that reviewed the case, then the bond will be forfeited and the Club will further lose the right to appeal any other decisions in that League Season and the next one. Further, the send-off punishment of the player or coach/staff member will be doubled (i.e., an automatic suspension of two (2) games).

Pardon my naivety, but does that imply that MLS teams can not make any appeal once their upper limit for appeals expires *(even for genuine cases)*?

Also, is this just an MLS thing or does a similar system exist in other leagues as well where no appeal can be made once the upper limit expires?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, MLS teams can not make any appeals once their upper limit for appeals expires. From [backlinesoccer.com](http://backlinesoccer.com/the-curious-case-of-red-card-appeals) article,

> The team is only allowed two unsuccessful appeals a season, and as a deterrent from this system being abused, if the ruling body determines the red card appeal is frivolous then the team loses the bond, loses the right to appeal any decision for the current season as well as the next season, plus the punishment of the red card appeal is doubled.

That's why we see many controversial red cards not reviewed in MLS. Examples: [1st](http://www.goal.com/en/news/orlando-city-to-accept-kaka-suspension-following/se60qoudlhdz1itmoiepsk9o5), [2nd](https://www.modernghana.com/sports/761727/mls-side-columus-crew-decides-not-to-appeal-jonathan-mensah.html)

I am still searching for system similar to MLS, will add that if I find.